# Why there is no ICC rankings for women's test cricket?

Tags: cricket, icc, ranking

ICC has been conducting [test cricket matches for women](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women%27s_Test_cricket) since 1934. We can also see some recent [test matches](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/593722.html) for women.

But, there is no official ICC rankings were provided by ICC for women's test cricket. [Rankings](http://www.relianceiccrankings.com/) are available only to ODIs and Twenty20I matches.

Is there any particular reason for not having rankings for women in Test matches?
**or**
Does ICC has any limitations(no. of matches/ no. of nations) to provide ranks for particular format of cricket?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Few countries play full Test Matches in Women's Cricket these days. Since 2007, there have been only 4 Women's test matches played, all being Australia playing England in the Women's Ashes. The last test played between any other nations was Netherlands vs South Africa in 2007.

With so few matches, there is no point having a rating system. Women's Test Cricket is essential defunct (unfortunately).

The source is Cricinfo Statsguru. Use [this](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=8;orderby=start;orderbyad=reverse;template=results;type=team;view=match) pre-made and sorted query to see the latest Women's test matches.